# searching for a tool/solution that allows angular to show forms and form elements dynamically based on metadata

Tags: angularjs, forms, dynamic

the forms in my app display themself based on metadata. 
In design mode the user should be able to change the form (metadata) by dragging all form elements (text, input ...) somewhere in the browsers window. I want to save the new metadata to display the changed form.
I wonder, if there is allready any solution or a tool.

Thanks in advance 
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Check this link - http://ngmodules.org/ which contains a detailed list of plugins developed for angularjs. I have found many useful plugins here.